# how to add prebuilt object files to executable in cmake

Tags: cmake

I have an `add_custom_target` that triggers a make for a project (that project does not use cmake!) and generates an object file. I would like to add this object file to an executable target in my project's cmake. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As of Cmake 3.9.6 you can import object libraries, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51344020/1151724 ...Although it is probably more ponderous for a single object who's path could just be put in a variable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
SET(OBJS
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/obj.o
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myProgram ${OBJS} <other-sources>)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
  ${OBJS}
  PROPERTIES
  EXTERNAL_OBJECT true
  GENERATED true
)
```

That worked for me. Apparently one must set these two properties, *EXTERNAL_OBJECT* and *GENERATED*.

Comment: The code snippet lacks of `add_executable()` call with object file as one of its argument. It confuses some readers, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209751/cmake-mingw-compiler-flag-finstrument-functions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Your comment is very valuable. I suggest you edited the answer yourself since almost a year has passed

Answer (score 22):

I've done this in my projects with [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
target_link_libraries(
    myProgram 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/obj.o
)
```

Any full path given to `target_link_libraries()` is assumed a file to be forwarded to the linker.

---

For CMake version >= 3.9 there are the `add_library(... OBJECT IMPORTED ..)` targets you can use.

See [Cmake: Use imported object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344020/cmake-use-imported-object)

---

And - see also [the answer from @arrowd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38609450/4763489) - there is the undocumented way of adding them directly to your target's source file list ([actually meant to support object file outputs for `add_custom_command()` build steps](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/70b4e1051e04be892c86aa3ff729d63ccf1f7771) like in your case).

Comment: It's assuming i'm trying to link a library, not a regular .o file when I try this.

Comment: @DrEval Yes, you need to know what CMake is doing here and that's the ugly part about this approach. I think it's also about your personal taste: Is an external object file more a "source file" or an "something to link with file".

Answer (score 4):

You can list object files along sources in `add_executable()` and `addlibrary()`:

```
add_executable(myProgram
   source.cpp
   object.o
)
```

The only thing is that you need to use `add_custom_command` to produce object files, so CMake would know where to get them. This would also make sure your object files are built before `myProgram` is linked.

Comment: I have tried this but it does not work! I did a verbose cmake and the object file is not mentioned at all during linking! I'm giving the full path using ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/objectfile.o

Comment: Does it exist at the moment you run CMake?

Comment: I've found the solution. It's similar to what you suggested only with a small adaptation. :)

Comment: @mkmostafa When you find the solution and take the time to comment, it'd be great to actually post what that was.

Comment: @josh the solution that mkmostafa found is the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `CMake version 3.9`:

```
# Imported object library
add_library(someObjsLib OBJECT IMPORTED)

set_property(TARGET someObjsLib PROPERTY 
    IMPORTED_OBJECTS /some/path/obj1.o
                     /some/path/obj2.o
)

add_executable(myExe $<TARGET_OBJECTS:someObjsLib>)
```

[IMPORTED_OBJECTS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_OBJECTS.html) && [Professional CMake](https://crascit.com/professional-cmake/)

Answer (score 0):

I posted entire "CMakeLists.txt" using suggestions in here. The code example is from [Derek Molly](http://derekmolloy.ie/hello-world-introductions-to-cmake/).

Before running this file, please make an Object file, "Student.o", from "Student.hpp" (located in "include_custom" folder) and "Student.cpp" using G++ like `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -I ../include_custom/ ../src/Student.cpp -c`. This is due to "GENERATED" as true in the "set_source+files_properties" function.

"CMakeLists.txt" example:

```
# ----- 1. Runtime requirement
# For O file CMake Version3.9.6 and up (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609303/how-to-add-prebuilt-object-files-to-executable-in-cmake)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.0)
project(my_question)

# ----- 2. Debugging

# ----- 3. Global variable

set(includes ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include_custom)
set(objs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/output/Student.o)
set(sources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/mainapp.cpp)

# ----- 4. Software tool

# ----- 5. Library
include_directories( ${includes} )

# ----- 6. Compile
add_executable( my_question ${sources} ${objs} )

set_source_files_properties(
  ${objs}
  PROPERTIES
  EXTERNAL_OBJECT true
  GENERATED true
)
```