# Cmake: Use imported object

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

*Although [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609303/how-to-add-prebuilt-object-files-to-executable-in-cmake) is a very similliar question, it predates the methodology I'm asking about ("imported object libraries"), which was added to Cmake in version 3.9.6 ~1 year ago(?) hence none of the answers there address this.*

---

I've just started using cmake and I'm trying to more or less replicate this kind of behaviour from a makefile:

```
foo: foo.cpp bar.o
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

bar.o:
    cp $(EXTERNAL_DIR)/bar.o .
```

So `bar.o` is just being copied in from outside.  It's not being built, etc.  Then it's compiled into the `foo` target.

[In the Cmake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries) this seems pretty straightforward; to import the .o file:

```
add_library(bar OBJECT IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(TARGET bar PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${EXTERNAL_DIR}/bar.o)
```

And to use it:

```
add_executable(foo $<TARGET_OBJECTS:bar> foo.cpp)
```

But when the build runs, I get all missing symbols for the stuff that's supposed to be in `bar.o` -- and run verbosely, it's clear why: Cmake never uses it for anything.  It's not mentioned in the compiler invocation, and grepping through the build directories, it's not mentioned in any of the generated makefiles either.

Further, I can change the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` to something non-existent and it doesn't care.  It runs exactly the same way.

What have I misunderstood here?  How do I get this done (and without having to add anything to `EXTERNAL_DIR`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add prebuilt object files to executable in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609303/how-to-add-prebuilt-object-files-to-executable-in-cmake)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach looks good with one notable exception (CMake's documentation is not clear here and is going to be fixed with CMake's next release; see [Merge Request 
!2216](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2216)).

You should use [`IMPORTED_OBJECTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_OBJECTS.html) target property instead of `IMPORTED_LOCATION`.

See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/command/add_library.html#imported-libraries:

> The most important such property is [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`}(https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION) (and its per-configuration variant [`IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION_CONFIG.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_LOCATION_%3CCONFIG%3E)) which specifies the location of the main library file on disk. Or, for object libraries, [`IMPORTED_OBJECTS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_OBJECTS.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_OBJECTS) (and [`IMPORTED_OBJECTS_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_OBJECTS_CONFIG.html#prop_tgt:IMPORTED_OBJECTS_%3CCONFIG%3E)) specifies the locations of object files on disk.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
add_executable(foo foo.cpp ${EXTERNAL_DIR}/bar.o)
```

For future reference, the CMake docs for `add_library(... OBJECT)` say:

> Object libraries cannot be imported, exported, installed, or linked.

Which partly explains why your original approach does not work.

Comment: Just a hint: the "linked" part is not true anymore for [CMake version >= 3.12](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/release/3.12.html).

Comment: @Florian: CMake 3.12 is not even released yet.  The solution I gave is simple and works with all versions.

Comment: Actually it looks like it is 3.9.6+ (in the synopsis under "Imported Libraries", OBJECT appears as an option for that version), and it does work using `IMPORTED_OBJECTS` instead of `_LOCATION` here (v. 3.11).  I think [this is the commit](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/eec93bceec5411e4409b5e3ee5dc301fca6fcbfd) from a year ago.