# How to add .obj file to the dependencies with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I tried this code to link `*.lib` files and `*.obj` files to my dependency.

```
SET(EXT_LIBS iphlpapi.lib json_writer.obj json_value.obj)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX "/link .obj")
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXT_LIBS} )
```

The code is working for only `*.lib` files.
And for the `*.obj` files it `".lib"` is automatically attached.
As a result,

```
iphlpapi.lib 
json_writer.obj.lib
json_value.obj.lib
```

But I want the result of

```
iphlpapi.lib 
json_writer.obj    
json_value.obj
```

How to disable automatic attaching ".lib" when I link `*.obj` files in cmake?

Comment: Have you tried other answers in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609303/how-to-add-prebuilt-object-files-to-executable-in-cmake), e.g. the first(accepted) one?

Comment: Yes, but it is not working.

Comment: Are you passing full paths to `.obj` files?

Comment: Not full path. just like this: 
SET(EXT_LIBS json_value.obj) TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXT_LIBS} )
As a result of this code, I get
json_value.obj.lib. I mean ".lib" is automatically attaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you must add the *.obj files to the Sources of the library/executable. Something along the lines of

```
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
        c:/full/path/to/windows/object/file.obj
        /full/path/to/linux/object/file.obj
    )
```

Alternatively you could [write a FindXXX.cmake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries#writing-find-modules) searching for your object files. Those should create imported Targets and use the imported Targets' location property for the source file list in the `add_xxxx()` call.

The third option also makes these object files available for sub-projects via an [imported Target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#id3).

Example for adding the Target without making an extra Findmodule. (Preferably in the root CMakeLists.txt)

```
    add_library(JSONObjects::json_writer OBJECT IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(JSONObjects::json_writer PROPERTIES IMPORTED_OBJECTS
        /absolute/path/to/linux/json_writer.obj
    )
```

and then in the consuming CMakeLists.txt

```
    set(ALL_FILES ${ALL_FILES}
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:JSONObjects::json_writer>
    )
    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ALL_FILES})
```