# How to disable auto ".lib" attaching when I add the dependencies with cmake?

Tags: cmake, object-files

I want to link the ".obj" file to my project.

Here is my code.

```
set(EXT_LIBS json_reader.obj json_writer.obj)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXT_LIBS})
```

But as a result I following files have been linked.

```
json_reader.obj.lib
json_writer.obj.lib
```

`".lib"` is automatically attached if it's not *.lib file.

I want next result

```
json_reader.obj
json_writer.obj
```

How can I link *.obj files to my project?

Comment: How this question differs from your [previons one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625884/how-to-add-obj-file-to-the-dependencies-with-cmake)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be included by doing this: `ADD_EXECUTABLE(myProgram ${OBJS} <other-sources>)` or in your case `ADD_EXECUTABLE(myProgram ${EXT_LIBS} <other-sources>)`

If you want to link differently for `debug` and `release`

```
if(${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} == "Debug")
    set(EXT_LIBS json_reader.obj json_writer.obj)
else()
    set(EXT_LIBS json_reader_alt.obj json_writer_alt.obj)
endif()
```

You can add the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` parameter to cmake-gui by adding the entry.
[image]

> A .LIB file is a collection of .OBJ files concatenated together with an index. There should be no difference in how the linker treats either.
>   [As per answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361074/8548828)

It seems to me that the [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/add_library.html#normal-libraries) only works on `.a` and `.lib` files.
And [`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries#overview) only adds system library files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  in my case it's not good solution.

Comment: can you add your case specific parameters to your question as to why you can't do that so people can give a better answer?

Comment: Hi, Tarick, I want to add different ".obj" files when build type is debug mode and release mode. Can you let me know how to do this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I configure the project with cmake-gui.exe, ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}  is empty value.
So it always compiles the else() case. How can I deal with this problem in CMakelist.txt?

Comment: Thank you again. If I set the value "Debug" manually, it would always compile the first case. Then how can I determine whether the visual studio build_type is debug or release in CMakelist.txt?