# Calling assembler function from C++, linkage error

Tags: c++, assembly, cmake, linkage

I am trying to call assembler function from C++ but facing linkage error. I am using Clang(Apple 11.0.0) on Mac OS and cmake.
Here is my cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(bitShiftAsm)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/func.o
    WORKING_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
    COMMAND nasm -f macho64 ../func.asm
)

SET(OBJS
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/func.o
)

add_executable(bitShiftAsm ${OBJS} main.cpp)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(
    ${OBJS}
    PROPERTIES
    EXTERNAL_OBJECT true
    GENERATED true
)
```

Assembler file:

```
global _my_fn
_my_fn:
    mov rax, rdi
    add rax, 100
    ret
```

C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" long my_fn(long in);

int main()
{
    cout << "Result: " << my_fn(3) << endl;
}
```

Linkage error is:

```
nasm -f macho64 ../func.asm
c++    -g -isysroot 
MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.14   -std=gnu++1z -o 
CMakeFiles/bitShiftAsm.dir/main.cpp.o -c    .../bitShiftAsm/main.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable bitShiftAsm
cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/bitShiftAsm.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
c++  -g -isysroot
MacOSX10.15.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.14 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,- 
headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/bitShiftAsm.dir/main.cpp.o ../func.o  - 
o bitShiftAsm 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_my_fn", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I have separate command to compile asm file and generate .o file from it. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting from the linker?

Comment: You forgot to make your function global. Add `global my_fn` to your assembly file. You might also need to rename it to `_my_fn` with a leading underscore.

Comment: I added it but still got the same linkage error.

Comment: For consistency, and to ensure the `add_executable()` call can *see* the `.o` file, use `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/func.o` instead of `../func.o`. Also, try setting the source file properties of the `.o` file in your CMake, using the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610428/3987854).

Comment: Also get your toolchain to show the commands it is running (no idea how to do that with CMake, maybe some verbose setting somewhere).

Comment: Yes, the verbose compiler output, such as `make VERBOSE=1`, would be helpful.

Comment: I tried everything but nothing helps. With verbose I am getting exact commands that are running but at the end the same error again and nothing more.

Comment: But what **are** the exact commands that are running?  Please tell us.

Comment: I added verbose logs. It seems that func.o is involved in linkage.

Comment: Does it exist in `..`? Have you added the `global _my_fn` and changed `my_fn:` to `_my_fn:`?

Comment: Well the error message says it all. _my_fn is undefined. You define my_fn. A little fun fact: C implementations may mangle names too! Most often by adding a leading underscore.

Comment: Yes, I have added everything that is in discussion. Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried just running `nm` or `objdump` on `main.cpp.o` and `func.o`? You can see exactly what symbols the linker is working with ...

Comment: Hm, I removed the build directory and it started working. Very strange. Thanks a lot.

Comment: CMake caches much of its variables, so when making changes to your CMake file, it is good practice to clear the CMake cache (i.e. by removing the build directory). This way, CMake runs from scratch and can recognize your changes. Please consider posting an answer showing what you changed in the code, so future visitors can understand the solution!