# Linking multiple objects files generated by Makefile to CMake subdirectory

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a list of object files generated by a Makefile stored under say `mylib` directory. I am trying to link these object files while compiling one of the sub-directories in my project (I don't want to generate an executable). Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -g")
set( CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON )
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" ".hpp")

include_directories(mylib)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib)

add_library(slib SHARED ${SOURCES})
```

That is, `mylib` directory contains `.h`, `.cc` and `.o` files I generated after running `make` on `mylib`. 
When I try to compile this, I get an `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error for `mylib` functions.

How can I link multiple precompiled object files generated by an external `make`? This question ([how to add prebuilt object files to executable in cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609303/how-to-add-prebuilt-object-files-to-executable-in-cmake)) gives a method to link a single object file. How do I do this for all the object files and generated a shared library instead of an executable?

Comment: You linked answer explicitely uses a list (of 1 but it could be more) object files.

Comment: You should find how GLOB_RECURSE works [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/file.html). This should help :)

Comment: @Frank: I agree. But I was looking for a wildcard based approach rather than listing all the object files.

Comment: @Unni: You need somehow to **list all object files** required for your library. It could be `file(GLOB)`, but it searches the files immediately at *configuration* stage. (That is, it won't find the files created during the *build* stage). As a possible approach - `GLOB` *source files* in your Makefile project, and transform resulted paths to the paths of object files which will be created by Make.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compile library "mylib" with [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/module/ExternalProject.html) (by direct call to `gcc`, for example) and, then use code like this:

```
add_library (slib SHARED ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (slib "mylib")
```

`add_dependencies` may be useful in some cases.